# What is the best way to take a back up of database every day at a specific time?

Tags: java, database, backup

What is the  best  way to take a back up of database every night at a specific time (say 12 am) through Java code ? [Oracle database , Windows XP]

I actually got asked this question in an interview.

Comment: Why through Java code? On which OS are you? Which DBMS is it?

Comment: http://oreilly.com/java/archive/quartz.html just go through this

Comment: Oracle database / Windows environment

Comment: I'm sure Oracle DB provides some backup solution. Why don't you use that one?

Comment: It's one of those questions that's simply perfect for eliminating whoever asked it as a potential employer. Because if any company thinks it's a good idea to do daily backups of databases through Java instead of one of the thousands of suitable solutions out there, or using the facilities of the DBMS itself, I'd sure get the hell out of there and never look back.

Comment: @G_H But maybe your comment is exactly what employer wanted to hear? :)

Answer (score 1):

It is better to schedule task on OS to execute some .bat (.sh) and do the DB back up.